# How to change background color of column based of comparing values over time with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I have a problem right now

I want to change the background color of a measure column in matrix table over time by comparing values
I want to give a specific color if the value of % zero has a positive evolution over time , and a specific color if the value has a negation evolution over time and if the value does not change , it keeps the change color
Refer to PNG to see my initial Matrix table and the Matrix table i want
Thanks for your feedback

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you'll need to add a few calculations.  You will need to adapt these to the real table names and columns in your own model:

**EDIT:** Added this calculation so that the measures can reference a base measure rather than a column:

```
SumOfValue = SUM(ConditionalFormatting[value])
```

**EDIT** updated prior value to work with a measure
Find the prior value:

```
PriorValue =
CALCULATE (
    LASTNONBLANKVALUE(ConditionalFormatting[Date], [SumOfValue] ),
    ConditionalFormatting[Date] < SELECTEDVALUE(ConditionalFormatting[Date])
)
```

**EDIT** Updated the status calc to refer to the formula
Calculate the color:

```
StatusColor = IF (
            [PriorValue] >= [SumOfValue] || ISBLANK([PriorValue]),
            "#FFFF00",
            "#8EA9DB"
        )
```

**EDIT** Added calc to get the last color applied:

```
LastStatusColor =
CALCULATE (
    LASTNONBLANKVALUE ( ConditionalFormatting[Date], [StatusColor] ),
    ConditionalFormatting[Date] < SELECTEDVALUE ( ConditionalFormatting[Date] )
)
```

**EDIT**  added calc for the final color logic:

```
FinalColor =
IF ( [PriorValue] = [SumOfValue], [LastStatusColor], [StatusColor] )
```

Once you have these measures, you can configure conditional formatting in the table.

In the value in the table, click on the arrow for more options and choose Conditional Formatting > Background Color

[image]

**EDIT** use final color field instead
In the dialogue, select `Field Value` and then select the `FinalColor` measure

[image]

**EDIT**  Updated image to show new complete result
Once this is done, you're table will look like this:

[image: Final result]

Comment: Thanks for your response but my ConditionalFormatting[value] is a measure and i can't call it And when tne evolution didn't change , i want the same color at the preceding date

Comment: Remove `SELECTEDVALUE()` around the `ConditionalFormatting[value]` and this should correct the formula.  Your example shows the color going yellow when it is the same as the prior, like in July for x3 -- please confirm that if the result is the same, you just want to repeat the color, whatever that is.

Comment: The second formula is ok but the first one isn't . i can't find why maybe because of MAX ( ConditionalFormatting[value] )

Comment: Since the first fomula doesn't work I used this one but i have both color in the first date column?
Can you help me find the problem .. Thanks 



PriorValue = 
            CALCULATE(
                ConditionalFormatting[value], FILTER(ALL(ConditionalFormatting[Date]),
                ConditionalFormatting[Date]< MAX(ConditionalFormatting[Date] ))

Comment: I'm going to update the calculations in the answer to match your model.  I broke things up into a couple of calculations for simplicity in the answer, but you might combine some of the logic together in the complete solution.  This includes the logic to keep the same color if the value hasn't changed

Comment: The answer is updated now

Comment: Many thanks, I just have a question is it possible to use aggregate function on a measure such as SUM(measure) ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but make sure the results are what you expect them to be